MatBlazor MatSelect control the order of MatOptions
I have created the following code using MatBlazor MatSelect:
<MatSelect Outlined="true" Id="class-status" TValue="int" @bind-Value="@myStatus">
  <MatOption Value="1">In service</MatOption>
  <MatOption Value="0">Out of service</MatOption>
</MatSelect>

But it keeps ordering it by the 'value' rather than the order I have coded it in.  I even tried changing it to 'bool' instead of 'int' and still seemed to order false first.
How can I control the order it is displayed in and make 'In Service' the default selected?

Hi @JustCoder, have you solved the problem? If not, can you tell me us the MatBlazor package version? And you can also create a minimal sample to reproduce the problem, then, we can try to give a solution based on it.

Hello
The response below was the solution but I ended up moving my application over to Mudblazor as I spotted Matblazor had not been updated for over a year and just did not seem to have the same level of use/support as Mudblazor.

To make the 'In Service' the default selected, you can set the myStatus value in the @{...} block, code like this:
@code {
    private int myStatus = 1; // Set default to 1 for "In service"
}
<MatSelect Outlined="true" Id="class-status" TValue="int" @bind-Value="@myStatus">
    <MatOption Value="1">In service</MatOption>
    <MatOption Value="0">Out of service</MatOption>
</MatSelect>

To control the option order displayed in the select control, you can use the following code to add the options and use the OrderBy or OrderByDescending method to sort the options.
@code {
    private int myStatus = 1; // Set default to 1 for "In service"

    //order by the option using OrderBy or OrderByDescending method.
    private List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> statusOptions = (new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
      {
          new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "In service"),
          new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "Out of service")
      }).OrderByDescending(c => c.Key).ToList();
}
<MatSelect Outlined="true" Id="class-status" TValue="int" @bind-Value="@myStatus">
    @foreach (var option in statusOptions)
    {
        <MatOption Value="@option.Key">@option.Value</MatOption>
    }
</MatSelect>

The result as below:
ASC result:

DESC result:

